# Android WebView не воспринимает сайты, написанные на React.js

Tags: java, reactjs, android-studio, android-webview

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании приложения в Android Studio на языке программирования Java. WebView просто не воспринимает сайты, написанные мною на реакте. Хотя сайты js и html прекрасно открываются и функционируют. С чем это может быть связано? Как исправить проблему?

P.S. не судите строго, это мое первое приложение, я новичок)

**Код MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final Activity activity = this;

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://fascinating-granita-3f1986.netlify.app/");

    setContentView(webView);
}
```

}

**Код activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <WebView
    android:id="@+id/WebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

В AndroidManifests дал разрешение на использование интернета.